# Aspx file call not working in IE

Tags: asp.net

The website: http://www.hilinehomes.com

There are several ASP.net pages that call a .aspx 'Contact us' file that includes a drop down to select different offices and their data. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, broken in IE.

The data for the pull-down box is in the Default.Master file. I am not an ASP.net programmer, but know just enough to make slight, occasional changes.

If you visit the site fresh in IE, the drop down works. If you select a drop down other than Puyallup and then refresh, the drop down breaks. If you clear temp files and refresh, it works again.

The code for 'contactbar.aspx':

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="contactbar.ascx.cs" Inherits="HiLine.Web.UserControls.contactbar" %>
<div id="sidebar-main">
<div class="sidebar" id="contact">
  <h4>
    Contact Us</h4>
  <select name="location" id="location">
    <option value="1">Puyallup, WA</option>
    <option value="8">Burlington, WA</option>
    <option value="10">Central Oregon</option>
    <option value="3">Centralia, WA</option>
    <option value="4">Grays Harbor, WA</option>
    <option value="13">Moses Lake, WA</option>
    <option value="2">Oly. Peninsula, WA</option>
    <option value="16">Roseburg, OR</option>
    <option value="9">Salem, OR</option>
    <option value="15">Spokane, WA</option>
    <option value="7">Tri-Cities, WA</option>
    <option value="14">Wenatchee, WA</option>
    <option value="5">Woodland, WA</option>    
    <option value="6">Yakima, WA</option>
  </select>
  <div id="default" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
    <p>
      Select one of our offices closest to the location where you intend to build a home.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="contactDiv" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <p id="address">
      1888 Belmont Loop<br />
      Woodland, WA 98674</p>
    <p id="phonefax">
      <b>Tel:</b> 360-225-1768<br />
      <b>Fax:</b> 360-225-7813</p>
    <p id="officehours">
      <b>Office Hours:</b><br />
      9:00-5:30 Monday-Saturday</p>
    <div id="featuresVary" style="margin: 10px; margin-left: 15px; font-size: 11px; clear: both; border: 1px solid white; padding: 4px;
      background-color: #f37121;">
      Features, Options and Promotional Offers May Vary By Location. Contact Your Local Sales Office For Additional Information or to make an after hours appointment.
    </div>
    <a href="contactform2.aspx">
      <img src="images/email_btn.gif" style="float: right; margin-right: 17px;" id="sendmail_btn" alt="Send Email" /></a>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background:none;padding-left:18px;padding-top:15px;margin-top:30px;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_US"></script><script type="text/javascript">FB.init("022348d39113d1fd3da56159b62598f7");</script><fb:fan profile_id="214974200273" stream="0" connections="6" logobar="1" width="180"></fb:fan>
  </div>  
 <img id="energy_star" src="images/energy_star.gif" />
  </div>
```

On the ASP.net pages, all that is listed in the code is:

```
<hiline:contact id="contact" runat="server" />
```

In the Default.Master file, this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var contactInfo = new Array();
        // [display address, gmaps address, phone/fax, office hours, model home]
        contactInfo["1"] = ["11210 Woodland Ave E.<br />Puyallup, WA 98373", "11210 Woodland Ave E., Puyallup, WA 98373", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+12538401722'>253-840-1722</a><br /><b>Fax:</b> 253-840-1836<br /><br /><a href='http://www.hilinehomespuyallup.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/webani.gif' width='175' height='30' /></a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["2"] = ["Call for an Appointment", "92 Kala Square Place Port Townsend, WA 98368", "<b>Tel:</b> (866) 789-3507", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:30<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["3"] = ["Call for an Appointment", "1213 Long Road, Centralia, WA 98531", "<b>Tel:</b> (866) 745-4553", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:30<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["4"] = ["306 4th St.<br />Satsop, WA 98583", "306 4th St., Satsop, WA 98583", "<b>Tel:</b><a class='mobile' href='tel:+13604824224'>360-482-4224</a><br /><br /><a href='http://www.hilinehomesgraysharbor.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/webani.gif' width='175' height='30' /></a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["5"] = ["1888 Belmont Loop Road<br />Woodland, WA 98674", "1888 Belmont Loop, Woodland, WA 98674", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+13602551768'>360-225-1768</a><br /><b>Fax:</b> 360-225-7813<br /><br /><a href='http://www.hilinehomeswoodland.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/webani.gif' width='175' height='30' /></a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["6"] = ["2410 Terrace Hts. Dr.<br />Yakima, WA 98901", "2410 Terrace Heights. Dr., Yakima, WA 98901", "<b>Tel:</b><a class='mobile' href='tel:+15095751722'> 509-575-1722<a/><br /><b>Fax:</b> 509-575-1851", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["7"] = ["5520 West Hood Ave.<br />Kennewick, WA 99336",         "5520 West Hood Ave. Kennewick, WA 99336", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+15097351722'>509-735-1722</a><br /><b>Fax:</b> 509-735-3415", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["16"] = ["Call for an Appointment", "2101 SE Stellers Eagle Street, Roseburg, OR 97470", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+15419571721'>541-957-1721</a><br /><br /><div id='webani'><a href='http://www.hilinehomesroseburg.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/webani.gif' width='175' height='30' /></a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["9"] = ["3935 Hagers Grove Rd. SE.<br />Salem, OR 97317",       "3935 Hagers Grove Rd. SE., Salem, OR 97317", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+15033991721'>503-399-1721</a><br />CCB# 181652<br /><br /><div id='webani'><a href='http://www.hilinehomessalem.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/webani.gif' width='175' height='30' /></a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["10"] = ["<b>Model Home:</b><br />1454 NW Maple Rim Court<br />Redmond, OR 97756", "<b>Model Home:</b><br />1454 NW Maple Rim Court<br />Redmond, OR 97756", "<b>Tel:</b><a class='mobile' href='tel:+15416471600'>541-647-1600</a><br /><br /><a href='http://www.hilinehomescentraloregon.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/webani.gif' width='175' height='30' /></a>", "<b>Model Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:00<br />Monday-Saturday"];
        contactInfo["14"] = ["1848 N Wenatchee Ave<br />Wenatchee, WA. 98801",      "1818 N Wenatchee Ave<br />Wenatchee, WA. 98801", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+15096631722'>509-663-1722</a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:30-5:30<br />Tuesday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["15"] = ["506 N Vercler St.<br />Spokane Valley, WA 99216",     "15320 E Marietta Ave. Suite #2<br />Spokane Valley, WA 99216", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+15093211000'>509-321-1000</a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />9:00-5:30<br />Monday-Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["13"] = ["1611 South Beaumont Drive<br />Moses Lake, WA 98837", "1611 South Beaumont Drive<br />Moses Lake, WA 98837", "<b>Tel:</b> <a class='mobile' href='tel:+15097642345'>509-764-2345</a>", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />10:00-5:00<br />Friday and Saturday", "1716"];
        contactInfo["8"] = ["489 Andis Road<br />Burlington, WA 98233",            "489 Andis Road Burlington, WA 98233", "<b>Tel:</b> 360-707-2112", "<b>Office Hours:</b><br />10:00-5:00<br />Friday and Saturday", "1716"];

        function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
        document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
        ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
        }

        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
        if (document.cookie.length>0)
          {
          c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          if (c_start!=-1)
            { 
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
            if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
            } 
          }
        return "";
        }

        function addListener(element, event, listener, bubble) {
          if(element != null)
          {
            if(element.addEventListener) {
              if(typeof(bubble) == "undefined") bubble = false;
              element.addEventListener(event, listener, bubble);
            } else if(this.attachEvent) {
              element.attachEvent("on" + event, listener);
            }
          }
        }

        //swaps out contact info
        function swapContactInfo () {
            officeSelect = document.getElementById("location");
            if(officeSelect != null)
            {
              whichOffice = officeSelect.options[officeSelect.selectedIndex].value;
              var defaultDiv = document.getElementById("default");
              var contactDiv = document.getElementById("contactDiv");
              var directionsDiv = document.getElementById("directions");
              setCookie("Office", whichOffice, 30);
              if(whichOffice != "none"){
                  myAddress = document.getElementById("address");
                  myAddress.innerHTML = contactInfo[whichOffice][0];  
                  myPhone = document.getElementById("phonefax");
                  myPhone.innerHTML = contactInfo[whichOffice][2];
                  myHours = document.getElementById("officehours");
                  myHours.innerHTML = contactInfo[whichOffice][3];
                  if(thisPage == "buildarea") {      
                      officeText = document.getElementById("officeName");
                      myOffice = officeSelect.options[officeSelect.selectedIndex].text;
                      if(myOffice=="graysharbor") {
                          myOffice = "grays harbor";
                      }
                      officeText.innerHTML = myOffice + " ";
                      directionsDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
                      directionsDiv.style.display = "block";
                  }
                  defaultDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                  defaultDiv.style.display = "none";
                  contactDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
                  contactDiv.style.display = "block";
              } else {
                  if(thisPage == "buildarea") { 
                      directionsDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                      directionsDiv.style.display = "none";
                  }
                  defaultDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
                  defaultDiv.style.display = "block";
                  contactDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                  contactDiv.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
        }
```

There is other code, but I think this is the relevant stuff.

Comment: Looks like the DIV wrapping the drop down isn't closed.

Comment: Thanks Leon - I added the rest of the code for that page that includes the closing Divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if commenting out

```
setCookie("Office", whichOffice, 30);
```

fixes your issue. It doesn't look like that cookie's result is used on that page, but this might break in the setCookie() function because different browsers implement API for cookies a little differently.

You will need to make sure that this cookies is in fact *not* used elsewhere...